# layout showing black background in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have recently updated to android studio 2.2 . Whenever I try to create a new project , I get the layout background as black.

It is how the layout looks like :

[image]

The screen background is black even running on the emulator.

Please help.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Thanks for the solutions ! My problem is solved.  In the res/styles folder , I just changed   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">  with    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

Answer (score 3):

Go to App Theme > Holo.Light, or choose another Light theme.

Comment: Holo is *so* last year. =p

Comment: Where in the IDE is App Theme?

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem as you. Try this, open you project's app module AndroidManifest.xml file, which is usually in ProjectDir/app/src/main directory. Then in a line which is

`android:theme="@style/AppTheme">`

try go to AppTheme's declaration by `Command + B` (Mac OS) or `Ctrl + B` (Windows) or right click menus' `goto` menu item. Finally, in the newly opened file, if you see a line

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">`

congrats, just change is to be

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

and you get a white background and blue ActionBar. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `AppBarLayout`. Android is applying styles, that are pre-defined in it i.e. it is picking styles from the `res/styles/` directory. You can change the background to whatever color you like by using, in your layout file under your parent layout tag, :

```
android:background="whatEverColorYouWant"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android Manifest, change your theme in application tag to

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

and then Run your app.

For viewing light in xml, change your "Theme in Editor" to AppCompat.Light